# c3p0 log4j2 implementation

Tags: java, logging, log4j2, c3p0

I inherited a java tomcat web project project and I am trying to get c3p0 logging enabled and I cannot get it working for the life of me.

I am using c3p0 with jdbc driver com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver and this seems to work great.

I've done some research and there is no log4j2.properties file, but there is a log4j2.xml file that has logging def in it.  I added c3p0 logger name in but I cannot seem to get it to work.

Regular logging is working.  What the application uses is

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger("TrackerLogger");
logger.info("HOLA");
```

I've tried adding this in various places but when i start up my java app, nothing is logging.

```
        <logger name="com.mchange.v2.c3p0">
        <level value="trace"/>
        </logger>
```

Here is my log4j2.file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="trace">
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="logFile" fileName="c:/Tracker/Logs/current.log" filePattern="c:/Tracker/Logs/%d{yyyy-MM-dd} tracker.log" immediateFlush="true" append="true">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%X] [%t] %-5level - %msg%n"/>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true"/>
            </Policies>   
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>

        <Logger name="com.mchange.v2.c3p0" level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="logFile"/>
        </Logger>
        <Root level="trace">
            <AppenderRef ref="logFile"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
    
</Configuration>
```

It's probably something simple and stupid i am missing.

Any suggestions?

Comment: That `<logger>` element should probably be a child of the `<Loggers> ... </Loggers>` element. Also, not sure if it matters, but try setting the level of the logger as an _attribute_ rather than as a child element (e.g., `<logger name="com.mchange.v2.c3p0" level="trace"/>`).

Comment: Tried that, still no go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might place in your `c3p0.properties` file (or as a System property)

```
com.mchange.v2.log.MLog=log4j2
```

c3p0 logs to its own logging facade, which supports fanning out to moust common log libraries.

See "[configuring logging](https://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_logging)" for more.

Comment: I didn't create a c3p0 properties file when enabled it.  I added c3p0 to pom.xml file.   In my xml file I set the  <bean id="userManagementDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close"> ETC.  I didn't need a propties file.  If i have to set one, where does that go?

Comment: Have you read c3p0 documentation?

Comment: yes, i still don't know where to create this properties files.

Comment: [define](https://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#c3p0_properties) the file `c3p0.properties` as a ClassLoader resource, that is somewhere in your application's `CLASSPATH`, at the top level. alternatively, you can set the same key-value pairs as System properties, e.g. by using `java -Dcom.mchange.v2.log.MLog=log4j2 ...` when you launch your application.